# iTunes Connect API: Mapping Country to Territory to get Timezone

Tags: api, timezone, app-store-connect, country-codes

I am using the **iTunes Connect API**, as defined here:
http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf

My issue is with:
*"Appendix D - Definition of Day and Week"*, sub-section: *"What time zone is the report date based on?"*

This sub-section has a table that maps "Territory" to "Time Zone".

It is not clear with the reporting data what value it need to map a "Country" to a "Territory" to get appropriate "Time Zone".

From the generated reporting schema, am I to use "Country Code", or am I to use "Provider Country", to determine "Territory"?

Answer (score 0):

The proper matching is to use "Country Code" to determine "Timezone Territory".